# .Net Using unit tests in a load test

Tags: .net, unit-testing, load-testing

I have an urgent question of using unit tests in a load test.

How to save global variables of the unit test class after running of each test method?. For example, I have a global variable in the unit test class, TestMethod1 modifies this variable and i want the TestMethod2 can use this variable (with his modified value) when it is called (by a virtual user of the load test) after the running of TestMethod1.

The settings of my load test : Test Mix Model is based on sequential order, Load Pattern is Constant (5 users), Run Settings: Use Specified iterations (iterations = 5 * number of methods).

I using VS2012 ultimate.

Have you any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Long Bien

Comment: if you have specific questions I'd suggest that you a new question and show the code you have, rather than making a general questions like these. Just a thought.

Comment: @bas: thanks for your suggest. I agree with you that it's not a good practice to make test cases dependent on each other but it's the best solution in my case. In fact, using a static global variable in the unit test class answered my need.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to have unit tests interact with each other using global variables. Each unit test should run atomic, and test specific behavior.

If you have the need to share some kind of setup behavior I'd use the SetUp attributes for that.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    // initialize whatever common functionality for your tests
}
```

You don't want to make test cases dependent on each other, because depending on test runner settings (parallel e.g.) the order of the tests can differ.

If you have very test specific setup behavior I'd make a dedicated test class for that specific test(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a BDD tool such as Specflow or Storevil. These can set up test 'scenarios' which you could use to co-ordinate your existing unit tests while still leaving them runnable in isolation.

For the context sharing both of those tools support data storage for the whole scenario which the tests can push data to or get data from. This would require modifying the test themselves and they would no longer really be unit tests, but it doesn't sound like unit testing is your goal here.